# Typescript: how to import class that was exported using `export = uuid`

Tags: typescript, import

I am attempting to use the node_module `uuid-js` in typescript.  I have installed both the module and the typing.

**Question:** How do I import the module?

---

The method that I want to use is `uuid.create`.

This is defined in `uuid-js`'s typings like this:

```
export = uuid;
declare class uuid {
    equals(uuid: uuid): boolean;
    ... 
    static create(version?: number): uuid;
    ...
}
```

---

The [typescript doc](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html) says that:

> When importing a module using export =, TypeScript-specific import
>   module = require("module") must be used to import the module.

Which seems to imply that I need to do this:

```
import UUID = require('uuid-js');
```

Which seems to compile to this:

```
const UUID = require("uuid-js")
```

Is there a reason I should use import instead of const in my code?  Why not just use the compiled code directly?

I feel like using require at all is odd.  Maybe, I am better off without using the typings or doing something else...?

What is the difference between using:

```
import UUID = require('uuid-js');
```

And

```
const UUID = require("uuid-js")
```

---

I did also try using a more traditional import strategy like Madara Uchiha suggested, but I get errors.

Using `import * as UUID from 'uuid-js'` results in:

```
error TS2497: Module '".../node_modules/@types/uuid-js/index"' resolves to a non-module entity and cannot be imported using this construct.
```

And using `import UUID from 'uuid-js';` results in:

```
error TS1192: Module '".../node_modules/@types/uuid-js/index"' has no default export.
```

Comment: According to an anonymous source that import syntax is legacy invented by TS and should not be used anymore

Comment: @SterlingArcher - What should be used?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `import something = require('something')` and `export = something` are legacy syntaxes invented by TypeScript before ES2015 modules were a thing.

Now, we use the standard module syntax, like so:

```
import * as UUID from 'uuid-js'; // if uuid-js has no export default
// or
import UUID from 'uuid-js'; // if it does.
```

The typings snippet you posed indicates that you should use the former.

Comment: I tried those as well, but with limited luck.  I updated my question to provide more info.

Answer (score 0):

> How are these different

`import` also imports the *types*. `const/require` does not.